# Replace values in one row by closest matching value in before and after row, and do this over multiple columns

Tags: r

I have found a solution to my problem (replacing certain values in multiple columns) but the solution is computationally expensive and takes extremely long to run on my data set which contains 1.4 million rows of data.

I have data that has been interpolated from one time stamp to another. The implication of this is that the newly interpolated data now has some values which contain decimals and are not a true reflection of the value they should be.

For example, in the following data:

```
G4<- data.frame(aX = c(0.968750, 0.970703, 0.980469, 0.949219, 0.960938, 0.966797, 0.935547, 0.875000, 0.882812, 0.871094, 0.871094),
                 aY = c(0.0468750, 0.0468750, 0.0410156, 0.0332031, 0.0585938, 0.1152340, 0.0996094, 0.0820312, 0.0781250, 0.0742188, 0.0859375),
                 aZ = c(0.234375, 0.234375, 0.242188, 0.236328, 0.234375, 0.246094, 0.236328, 0.228516, 0.236328, 0.287109, 0.289062),
                 Time = c("12/7/2013 15:04:30.496", "12/7/2013 15:04:30.536", "12/7/2013 15:04:30.577", "12/7/2013 15:04:30.617", "12/7/2013 15:04:30.657", "12/7/2013 15:04:30.697", "12/7/2013 15:04:30.736", "12/7/2013 15:04:30.776", "12/7/2013 15:04:30.815", "12/7/2013 15:04:30.855", "12/7/2013 15:04:30.895"),
                 Position = c(6.00000, 6.00000, 6.00000, 6.00000, 6.00000, 4.05629, 3.00000, 3.00000, 3.00000, 3.00000, 3.00000),
                 PreyEvent = c(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.647905, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000),
                 PreyEventDetail = c(0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 1.29581, 2.00000, 2.00000, 2.00000, 2.00000, 2.00000),
                 Capture = c(0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 1.94371, 3.00000, 3.00000, 3.00000, 3.00000, 3.00000),
                 LikelyPrey = c(0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000,   1.29581, 2.00000, 2.00000, 2.00000, 2.00000, 2.00000),
                 Video = c( 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

You will see that for columns which contain classes of animal behavior, certain values that have arisen from the interpolation contain decimals and rather need to be matched to the closest whole integer in the row above or below.

The example code below, iterates over each row of interest and picks the necessary value that has the closest match, and then replaces it.

```
temp.dat <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(G4)){

  print(i)
  t1 <- G4[i,]
  t1before <- G4[i-1,]
  t1after <- G4[i+1,]

  ##Position
  x1 <- c(t1before$Position,t1after$Position)
  replace.value.pos <- x1[which.min(abs(x1 - t1$Position))]
  t1$Position <- replace.value.pos

  ##PreyEvent
  x2 <- c(t1before$PreyEvent,t1after$PreyEvent)
  replace.value.pe <- x2[which.min(abs(x2 - t1$PreyEvent))]
  t1$PreyEvent <- replace.value.pe

  ##PreyEventDetail
  x3 <- c(t1before$PreyEventDetail,t1after$PreyEventDetail)
  replace.value.pdet <- x3[which.min(abs(x3 - t1$PreyEventDetail))]
  t1$PreyEventDetail <- replace.value.pdet

  ##Capture
  x4 <- c(t1before$Capture,t1after$Capture)
  replace.value.c <- x4[which.min(abs(x4 - t1$Capture))]
  t1$Capture <- replace.value.c

  ##LikelyPrey
  x5 <- c(t1before$LikelyPrey,t1after$LikelyPrey)
  replace.value.lp <- x5[which.min(abs(x5 - t1$LikelyPrey))]
  t1$LikelyPrey <- replace.value.lp

  ##Video
  x6 <- c(t1before$Video,t1after$Video)
  replace.value.vid <- x6[which.min(abs(x6 - t1$Video))]
  t1$Video <- replace.value.vid

  temp.dat <- rbind(temp.dat,t1)

}
## Compare new data frame with original
temp.dat
G4
```

However, this code is inefficient and I am struggling to find a faster alternative.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I ran your for loop, I received this error message `Error in rbind(temp.dat, t1) : object 'temp.dat' not found`

Comment: Just initialize temp.dat <- NULL

Comment: @Jono There's a discrepancy between your code and your verbal description of the required behavior. In your verbal description, you imply that only non-integral values should be replaced with the nearest value (above or below). But your code will replace *every* value with the nearest value (above or below), regardless whether it is integral or non-integral. Your example input doesn't expose this (mis)behavior, but if you had a column with sequential integers (e.g. `Position=c(1,2,3,...)`, then it would be changed to `Position=c(2,1,2,...)` in the output. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Jono Second question: Is it a guarantee that every non-integral value will be surrounded (both above and below, except for the top row (no above) and bottom row (no below)) by an integral value that would be acceptable as a replacement for that non-integral value?

Comment: I assume if you just round all the numbers it won't work? But then it seems to me that the method you suggest could give you erroneous classes as well. It would be really better to solve the issue upstream if you can

Comment: @bgoldst First question: I see what you are saying and apologies for this oversight. To follow onto your second question: Yes, it is a guarantee.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, rounding will not work as I will get erroneous classes as you suggest. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why your code is inefficient is that you are looping over rows, rather than columns. In R, efficiency tends to require *vectorization*, which means processing an entire vector in one shot. Your code is effectively processing one cell of the table at a time. In R, data.frames are internally implemented as a list of vectors, where each internal vector represents one column of the table. We need to process each column vector in one shot.

---

As I mentioned in my comment, your example input does not expose all cases that we would need to consider in order to communicate all aspects of the required behavior, or, equivalently, to verify correctness of a solution.

Here's a better test case, which consists of 6 columns of random doubles rounded to the nearest tenth (so some will be integral, most will be non-integral) each sandwiched between two integers (above and below), guaranteeing they will be valid replacement values:

```
set.seed(2L);
cns <- c('Position','PreyEvent','PreyEventDetail','Capture','LikelyPrey','Video');
NR <- 11L; NC <- length(cns);
input <- setNames(nm=cns,as.data.frame(replicate(NC,ifelse(1:NR%%2L,round(dig=1L,runif(NR,1,9)),sample(1:9,NR,T)))));
input;
##    Position PreyEvent PreyEventDetail Capture LikelyPrey Video
## 1       2.5       7.7             8.6     4.1        6.9   1.2
## 2       7.0       5.0             8.0     4.0        2.0   9.0
## 3       5.6       3.8             8.8     2.7        8.8   4.0
## 4       4.0       8.0             6.0     4.0        9.0   3.0
## 5       8.6       2.2             5.0     3.2        4.0   7.6
## 6       9.0       7.0             7.0     1.0        3.0   6.0
## 7       2.0       8.7             1.1     1.3        4.7   8.0
## 8       5.0       9.0             6.0     2.0        9.0   7.0
## 9       4.7       1.1             6.5     2.5        4.4   8.6
## 10      6.0       2.0             8.0     9.0        2.0   2.0
## 11      5.4       7.5             3.2     3.3        1.9   1.3
```

---

Here's my solution:

```
output <- input;
for (cn in cns) {
    isBelowCloser <- c(T,diff(abs(diff(output[[cn]])))<0,F);
    nonIntegralIndexes <- which(abs(output[[cn]]-round(output[[cn]]))>=1e-8);
    output[[cn]][nonIntegralIndexes] <- output[[cn]][nonIntegralIndexes+isBelowCloser[nonIntegralIndexes]*2L-1L];
}; ## end for
output;
##    Position PreyEvent PreyEventDetail Capture LikelyPrey Video
## 1         7         5               8       4          2     9
## 2         7         5               8       4          2     9
## 3         7         5               8       4          9     4
## 4         4         8               6       4          9     3
## 5         9         7               5       4          4     6
## 6         9         7               7       1          3     6
## 7         2         9               6       1          3     8
## 8         5         9               6       2          9     7
## 9         5         2               6       2          2     7
## 10        6         2               8       9          2     2
## 11        6         2               8       9          2     2
```

---

My solution loops over each target column of the table, identifying it by name, `cn`. Alternatively, you could use integer column indexes if you wanted.

Notice that I don't store the column vector in a temporary local variable; I always access it directly. This can save processing time, since it allows us to modify the vector in-place, rather than modifying a copy and then having to write it back into the original data.frame. Also note that, because of this in-place modification, it makes sense to copy the input object to a new output object so that we can preserve the original input for comparison purposes (of course, you don't need to do this in your final implementation).

There are three important statements in my solution, which I will describe below.

---

## `isBelowCloser` computation

First, and perhaps the most critical step, is identifying whether the *above* value is closer to the current value, or whether the *below* value is closer, for all values in the column vector. It's important to recognize that this is going to be a vectorized operation, so there's no "single" current value; the vectorized operation will run through the entire column vector and produce a vector as a result value.

Let's look at each piece of the statement from the inside out:

---

```
output[[cn]]
```

This simply indexes out the column vector.

---

```
diff(output[[cn]]))
```

This performs a subtraction between each adjacent pair of elements in the vector. Therefore, it computes in a single operation all differences that will be required for all replacement decisions for the entire column vector.

Note that the difference vector will be one element shorter than the column vector. This is because it produces one difference element for each *pair* of input vector elements.

Keep in mind the correspondence between the indexes of the difference vector compared to the indexes of the column vector. For example, for column element 2, difference element 1 represents the difference between column element 2 and its "above" element, and difference element 2 represents the difference between column element 2 and its "below" element.

---

```
abs(diff(output[[cn]]))
```

Since we're only interested in the *absolute distance* between the two candidate replacement values, we must ignore any sign in the difference elements, and therefore must take the absolute value of the difference vector.

---

```
diff(abs(diff(output[[cn]])))
```

This second-level difference compares the two candidate distances. It therefore tells us which is closer to the original column element.

Note that this will now be two elements shorter than the original column vector.

---

```
diff(abs(diff(output[[cn]])))<0
```

The above produces a logical vector that tells us which column elements have their "below" value closer than the "above" value. If the second-level difference is less than zero, that means the distance to the "below" element was less than the distance to the "above".

---

```
c(T,diff(abs(diff(output[[cn]])))<0,F)
```

Wrapping the logical vector in a preceding true and a following false value is necessary to handle the first and last rows. For those rows, the replacement value can only come from the one side for which there is an existent value. Hence, the top row must take its replacement value from the "below" element, and the bottom row the "above" element.

This wrapping restores the length of this intermediate vector to that of the original column vector. Hence, its indexes now correspond to the original column vector. In other words, the nth element of this intermediate vector represents whether the nth element of the column vector should take its replacement value from its "below" element (true) or "above" element (false).

The above expression is assigned to the `isBelowCloser` local variable for use in the final statement.

---

## `nonIntegralIndexes` computation

Since your question implied that you only want to replace non-integral values with their closest adjacent (above or below) value, we must compute which elements of the column vector are non-integral, so we can selectively modify only those elements.

---

```
output[[cn]]
```

Once again, we must extract the target column vector in-place.

---

```
round(output[[cn]])
```

To jump ahead, we will be comparing the distance between the column element and its nearest integer in order to decide if it is sufficiently far from its nearest integer to be considered "non-integral". Hence, we need to compute the closest integer using `round()`.

---

```
abs(output[[cn]]-round(output[[cn]]))
```

This computes the aforementioned distance.

---

```
abs(output[[cn]]-round(output[[cn]]))>=1e-8
```

This compares the distance against a small tolerance, such that only values that are closer than the tolerance to their nearest integer will be considered integers.

---

```
which(abs(output[[cn]]-round(output[[cn]]))>=1e-8)
```

In the final statement, it will be useful to have integer indexes of the non-integral elements, rather than a logical vector, so it's helpful to run `which()` here to perform that transformation.

The above result is assigned to `nonIntegralIndexes` for use in the final statement.

---

## Replacement statement

The final statement within the column loop actually applies the replacement.

---

```
isBelowCloser[nonIntegralIndexes]
```

We start by extracting, for non-integral elements only, the logical value that represents whether its "below" element is closer to it (true) or its "above" element is closer to it (false).

---

```
isBelowCloser[nonIntegralIndexes]*2L-1L
```

By multiplying by 2 and subtracting 1, we convert the false and true logical values into -1 and 1, respectively.

---

```
nonIntegralIndexes+isBelowCloser[nonIntegralIndexes]*2L-1L
```

Adding the -1 and 1 values to `nonIntegralIndexes` shifts the index to its winning replacement index.

---

```
output[[cn]][nonIntegralIndexes+isBelowCloser[nonIntegralIndexes]*2L-1L]
```

We then index out the winning replacement elements from the original column vector.

---

```
output[[cn]][nonIntegralIndexes] <- ...
```

Finally, we assign the winning replacement elements to the non-integral offending elements to replace them.

Comment: This code is monumentally faster than my answer. +1 and hope this well deserved answer is accepted.

Comment: @bgoldst Many thanks for this answer!! I will go over it slowly to fully understand it. However, it is working brilliantly on my full data set and what was expected to take about 83 hours is now achieved in a few seconds! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is faster or not, but I went with determining which rows would need changing first, and then replacing those, so you don't loop over all of the rows. Let me know how the speed works

```
some <- function(column){
  x <- column
  t.up.down <- cbind(c(x[-1], NA), c(NA, x[-length(x)]))
  rrows <- which(t.up.down[,1] != t.up.down[,2])
  change <- rep(NA, length(rrows))
  for(i in rrows){
    change[which(rrows == i)] <- t.up.down[i,][which.min(abs(t.up.down[i,] - x[i]))]
  }
  x[rrows] <- change
  x
}
apply(G4[,6:10], 2, some)
```

You other option would be applying this with the data.table package.

Comment: This answer also works exceptionally quickly on my data set, thank you very much! For interest though, there do seem to be a few nuances where some cells are 'missed' and remain as decimals when I run the code on my full data set.